# Problems concatenating adjusted volume videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have taken a number of video clips and adjusted their volumes using ffmpeg before then trying to concatenate them (using ffmpeg), but whereas I can watch the individually adjusted volume clip files AND hear the adjusted volume okay, the final concatenated version contains the video but no audio.

The commands I use to adjust the volume are:

```
> ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet.ts"


> ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet.ts" -vol 409 -vcodec copy  "E:/_Videos/Test/snippet_v1.6.ts"
```

The command I am using the concat is:

```
> ffmpeg -y -progress progressinfo.dat -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:/_Videos/Test/concat.txt" -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/_Videos/Test/_MERGED.mp4"
```

The output from this is below, but there are multiple errors listed similar to this...

```
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] More than one AAC RDB per ADTS frame is not implemented. 
Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, 
it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The full output....

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libx

ml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, concat, from 'E:/_Videos/Test/concat.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 136 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000284495c5c40] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'E:/_Videos/Test/_MERGED.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] More than one AAC RDB per ADTS frame is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 00000284490f6580] channel element 3.11 is not allocated
.
.
.
```

I have tried several different methods to adjust the volume and I have tried this on version 4.2.3 and the latest 4.4.1 but both fail with the same error. (I am on Windows 10)

(concatenating the original .ts files without adjusting the volume works ok).

What am I doing wrong (how do you adjust the volume of an mp4 before concatenating it back in with other mp4s)?

Comment: Why are you converting from MP4 to TS, and back to MP4? I tried to reproduce the issue, but the problem is not reproducible (using FFmpeg 4.4.1). There is a chance the problem is related to your input files.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue using synthetic video with audio. You are invited to follow my "reproducing instructions" (it's a bit hard to describe in comments, but I will try)...

Comment: **1.** Create synthetic video with stereo audio: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 44100 -t 10 snippet.mp4`

Comment: **2.** Duplicate `snippet.mp4` to `snippet2.mp4` and `snippet3.mp4`

Comment: **3.** Execute you conversion to TS: `ffmpeg -y -i snippet.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts snippet.ts` and `ffmpeg -y -i snippet.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts snippet2.ts` and `ffmpeg -y -i snippet.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts snippet3.ts`

Comment: **4.** Set the volume: `ffmpeg -y -i snippet.ts -vol 409 -vcodec copy -acodec aac snippet_v1.6.ts` and `ffmpeg -y -i snippet2.ts -vol 409 -vcodec copy -acodec aac snippet2_v1.6.ts` and `ffmpeg -y -i snippet3.ts -vol 409 -vcodec copy -acodec aac snippet3_v1.6.ts`. Note: I am getting a warning message: *-vol has been deprecated. Use the volume audio filter instead.*, but I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: **5.** Create the file `concat.txt` with the following 3 text lines: `file 'c:\Tmp\snippet_v1.6.ts'` and `file 'c:\Tmp\snippet2_v1.6.ts'` and `file 'c:\Tmp\snippet3_v1.6.ts'`

Comment: **6.** Apply concatenation: `ffmpeg -y -progress progressinfo.dat -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -vf  "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" _MERGED.mp4`. There are no errors...

Comment: HUGE Thanks Rotem - that did the trick (although the sound was getting out of sync with the video - corrected with the addition of a "-async 1" added). See the posted answer below.

Comment: Concatenating the synthetic video were meant to show that the problem is not reproducible. I am glad it helped you solve the problem some how...

Answer (score 0):

So the solution (as given by Rotem [a BIG thank you to Rotem] in the comments above) seems to be as Rotem said, but with the small addition of using "-async 1" to stop the sound from coming out of sync with the video.

The full set of commands I used was as follows:

```
// process the first clip (from a 640x480 30frames/s video)....

// Pull out a snippet from clip1.mp4 (39.51 seconds to 43.701 seconds...
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/clip1.mp4" -ss 39.51 -to 43.701 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f1.mp4" 2>&1

// Create synthetic video with stereo audio...
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 44100 -t 10  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f1.ts" 2>&1

// Execute conversion to TS
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f1.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f1.ts" 2>&1

// Set the volume...
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f1.ts" -vol 25 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -async 1  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f1_v0.1.ts" 2>&1

 
// now do the same for the next clip (with no volume adjust)...
// (a 1280x720 25frames/s video)...
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/clip2.mp4" -ss 0 -to 5.05 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f2.mp4" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 44100 -t 10  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f2.ts" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f2.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f2.ts" 2>&1

 

// and the same for the next clip (with volume adjusted down)...
// (a 1280x720 25frames/s video)...
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/clip2.mp4" -ss 0 -to 5.05 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f3.mp4" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 44100 -t 10  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f3.ts" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f3.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f3.ts" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f3.ts" -vol 76 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -async 1  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f3_v0.3.ts" 2>&1

 

// and the same for the next clip (with volume adjusted up)...
// (a 1280x720 25frames/s video)...
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/clip2.mp4" -ss 0 -to 5.05 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f4.mp4" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 44100 -t 10  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f4.ts" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f4.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f4.ts" 2>&1
ffmpeg -y -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f4.ts" -vol 409 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -async 1  "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/f4_v1.6.ts" 2>&1


// then create a concat.txt file with the following contents
file 'f1_v0.1.ts'
file 'f2.ts'
file 'f3_v0.3.ts'
file 'f4_v1.6.ts'


// concatenate the listed files into the final _MERGED.mp4 file.
ffmpeg -y -progress progressinfo.dat -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:/_Videos/Test/tmp/concat.txt" -vf  "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black"  "E:/_Videos/Test/_MERGED.mp4" 2>&1
```

(I don't suppose anyone knows how to do cross-fades between the first and second clips now?)

Thanks